# Changing Frequency of PWM Pin on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, frequency

I am trying to change the frequency of the PWM output from an Arduino Uno R3 (Been using Pin 9) to 200 Hz with a duty cycle of 20%. This is for an ESC that is connected to a 12V motor, and I know the ESC works as if I input a 200 HZ wave from a waveform generator the motor runs. However, I have been finding it difficult to do the same thing with an Arduino Uno and I believe it is due to the frequency being a default of 490 Hz, so I need a way to change that frequency to 200 Hz. Are there any libraries or specific ways to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: please add your code to the post ... format as "code"

Comment: Haven't used a library for this yet, but you can find promising results in a web search. Like [this library](https://github.com/matzefriedrich/arduino-pwm-frequency-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use my newly-created [**AVR_PWM**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/AVR_PWM) library to shield you from dealing with complex hardware registers

For example

```cpp
#include "AVR_PWM.h"

#if ( PWM_USING_ATMEGA2560 )
  // Pins tested OK in Mega
  //#define pinToUse      12            // Timer1B on Mega
  //#define pinToUse      11            // Timer1A on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       9            // Timer2B on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       2            // Timer3B on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       3            // Timer3C on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       5            // Timer3A on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       6            // Timer4A on Mega
  //#define pinToUse       7            // Timer4B on Mega
  #define pinToUse       8            // Timer4C on Mega
  //#define pinToUse      46            // Timer5A on Mega
  //#define pinToUse      45            // Timer5B on Mega
  //#define pinToUse      44            // Timer5C on Mega

#elif ( PWM_USING_ATMEGA_32U4  )
  // Pins tested OK on 32u4
  //#define pinToUse      5            // Timer3A on 32u4
  #define pinToUse      9            // Timer1A on 32u4
  //#define pinToUse      10            // Timer1B on 32u4

#else

  // Pins tested OK on Nano / UNO
  #define pinToUse      9            // Timer1A on UNO, Nano, etc
  //#define pinToUse     10            // Timer1B on UNO, Nano, etc
  //#define pinToUse      5               // Timer0B on UNO, Nano, e
  //#define pinToUse       3            // Timer2B on UNO, Nano, etc
#endif

//creates pwm instance
AVR_PWM* PWM_Instance;

float frequency;
float dutyCycle;

void setup()
{
  Serial.print(F("\nStarting PWM_Basic on "));
  Serial.println(BOARD_NAME);
  Serial.println(AVR_PWM_VERSION);

  //assigns PWM frequency of 200 Hz and a duty cycle of 0%
  PWM_Instance = new AVR_PWM(pinToUse, 200, 0);
}

void loop()
{
  frequency = 200;
  dutyCycle = 20;

  PWM_Instance->setPWM(pinToUse, frequency, dutyCycle);

  delay(10000);
  dutyCycle = 90;

  PWM_Instance->setPWM(pinToUse, frequency, dutyCycle);

  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to use Timer 2 (Pin D3) this code will do it:

```
void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (3, OUTPUT);

  TCCR2A = bit (WGM20) | bit (WGM21) | bit (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2B on compare
  TCCR2B = bit (WGM22) | bit (CS20) | bit (CS21) | bit (CS22); // prescaler of 1024
  OCR2A =  77;    // zero relative  
  OCR2B =  15;    // 20% duty cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop()
  {
  // do other stuff here
  }
```

More information on the Atmega328P timers on [my page about timers](http://gammon.com.au/timers).

The figure 77 is obtained from:

```
16000000 / 1024 / 78 = 200.32
```

In other words, the prescaler of 1024 is divided into the clock of 16 MHz, and then we count up to 78, giving a result of just over 200. I actually use 77 because the timer is zero-relative (it counts from 0 to 77, giving 78 counts). This means the frequency is slightly out (it will be 200.32 Hz rather than 200 but that could be close enough).

---

You could also do it with Timer 1 (pin D10) to get slightly more accurate results, like this:

```
void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (10, OUTPUT);

  // mode 15
  TCCR1A = bit (WGM10) | bit (WGM11) | bit (COM1B1); // fast PWM, clear OC1B on compare
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (WGM13) | bit (CS11);   // fast PWM, prescaler of 8
  OCR1A = 10000 - 1;   // what to count to
  OCR1B = 2000 - 1;    // duty cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop()
  {
  // do other stuff here
  }
```

In this case I have used a prescaler of 8 and a count-up value of 10000, as follows:

```
16000000 / 8 / 10000 = 200
```

In this case the answer is exactly 200, which will be more accurate than the 200.32 obtained from using Timer 2. That is because Timer 1 is a 16-bit timer and has higher resolution.